# Axial force in threaded axis

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm trying to calculate the axial force that is generated in a vertical threaded axis (arrow in picture) when a force of 100N is applied to a handle perpendicular to the axis (circled in picture). [image]

I've found various websites and calculators but I'm not sure which one is correct as they give me different solutions.

The torque generated in the axis is 14.35Nm and the thread is an M30x2. How can I calculate the correct axial force?

Answer (score 3):

The truth is that you can't just calculate it easily, mostly because a good portion of the axial force depends upon how much of the torque goes into overcoming the friction in the joint. The total friction is dependent on the coefficient of friction between the threads and between the parts of the fastener(s) that contact the surface of whatever is being bolted together. Those coefficients in turn are dependent on things like surface finish of the mating surfaces, lubrication and thread tolerances all of which vary, even within "identical" joints.